# "do-catch" statement in Swift executing four times?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm having a small issue with a program I'm writing. It's meant to read a .txt file of trail names and populate a TableView. For some reason, the do - catch statement inside the switch case is running four times instead of once. Can someone help me understand why? (New to Swift and iOS.)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch np {
    case "Acadia":

        let filename = "/Users/michaeltheadley/Desktop/Trailr/Data/National/National_Parks/Acadia/acadia_trails.txt"

        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile:filename, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            count = contents.components(separatedBy: .newlines).count
            print("the situation")

            // why is this block being executed x4 ??

            let lines : [String] = contents.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            for item in lines {
                trails_array.append(item)
                print(item)
                print(trails_array.count)
            }
        }
        catch _ as NSError {
            return 0
        }


        return count
```

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called per each section, each time you reload your tableView. So either you're reloading your tableView multiple times, or you have multiple sections.

Comment: Just a comment. I wouldn't recommend you to make complex calculations inside 'numberOfRowsInSection' or other tableview/data-source delegate methods. Especially on main queue. This method should be as lightweight ad possible, and the processing / disk access should be done on background queue, before the tableView loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your numberOfSections in tableview, numberrows is called 4 times only if you have 4 sections